# Need help creating PHP regex

Tags: php, regex

I've created a template engine, and now I want to get all remaining encapsulated strings ([[name]] or [[[name]]]). I've tried several things, including: `([[(.{2,})]])`.

If there is any good tutorial/source on Regex I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You should escape the `[` like this, `\[\[\w+\]\]`. You can start on regex here: https://regexone.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the ([[...]]) :

```
preg_match_all('/\(\[\[.*?\]\]\)/',
    "XXX ([[abc]]) YYY ([[def]])",
    $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
var_dump($out);
```

For the [[[...]]]

```
preg_match_all('/\[\[\[.*?\]\]\]/',
    "XXX ([[abc]]) YYY ([[def]])",
    $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
var_dump($out);
```